# How to store a text variable and have it typed out using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to store line 1 of a text document and then retrieve the value and send it as text.  I have tried as below (I know that this should be simple, but I am almost stumped):

```
  FileReadLine, texttoenter, textdoc.txt, 1
    Sendinput, %texttoenter%
```

I can use `variblename := "this is text"` to get it to store.  And then use ListVars to see that it did.

My goal is to make it store the variables from a text file as text and be able to enter it into a text field from that variable. I am also unable to use FileReadLine, OutputVar, Filename, LineNum and get it to even store, because when I go to ListVars it is still the same as starting value.

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work? If you use `msgbox %texttoenter%` does your line get read?

Comment: No, I can use ListVars and manually store the varible, such as variblename := "this is text" to get it to store.  I want to make it store the varibles from a text file as text and be able to enter it into a text field from that varible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also other options

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros/Directory.htm
you can easy use them like this: (@AppDataDir & "\textdoc.txt")

If the Text file is in the same folder like the AutoIt Script you can also use the `@ScriptDir` command,  using it the same way as `@AppDataDir`

Ref: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros/AutoItRelated.htm

Comment: Thanks, I believe that this will help others also.  I have seen this question asked on other sites before I came here and was able to get help.  Thank You for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

### **FIXED**

With a little playing around I found that ***I needed to list the FULL file path of the file*** and it now stores to the variable and outputs it.

Thanks for the time that you were willing to spend to consider my question and to try to help me answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried the SetWorkingDir command, this allows you to set the path once instead of repeating it for every file command.

Comment: If your text file is in the same directory as your script then it should be able to find the file without the full path.

Comment: It was in the same folder, that is what i thought.  That is also why I did not specify the path in the first script.

Comment: Relative paths in AHK depend on the current working directory. The working directory of a process is set by its caller. While Windows Explorer usually sets the working dir to the script file's directory, it may vary depending on who calls the script. To ensure that you use the script's path as the working dir, put `SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%` at the top of your script, as Robert pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

1- FileReadLine, OutputVar, C:(your File), 1

2- msgbox, %OutputVar%